# A perl/cgi script for uploading files

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

I've tried to run this script: http://www.seaglass.com/file-upload-pl.html. in Apache. Since I'm running a win7 x64, I modified the script, so it goes:
    `#! C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe -wT`
instead of just
    `#! /usr/bin/perl`
The page runs smoothly, but any uploading attempts fail with a `Can't open /tmp/outfile for writing - No such file or directory` error.
I have created a `/tmp/outfile` directory and a`/tmp/outfile.txt` file.
I'm really new to Perl, and thus don't know what could be wrong.
Please advise.

Comment: Yes, ask a different question, but post a link to it here.  If I don't get to it, someone else will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/tmp/outfile is the output filename, not a directory name.  Create C:\tmp, but remove C:\tmp\outfile if you really created that directory too.

Answer (score 0):

Unix path components are delimited using forward slashes, not backslashes, drives cannot be seen explicitly in the path. Perl can handle `/` as path separator on Windows, treating `C:` as filesystem root. *(Thanks, jimtut!)* Therefore Unix path `/tmp/outfile` translates to `C:\tmp\outfile` on Windows. It is path to a (possibly non-existent) file, where the uploaded contents should be stored.

If you want to be really sure about portability of your code, use File::Spec module to build the paths. It allows avoiding explicitly writing path separator (`/` on Unix, `\` on Windows).

When using Windows-style paths, remember to double the `\` when writing it into a double-quoted string. (`"C:\\tmp\\outfile"`) The escaping issue is the same as in shell, PHP and many other languages…

Comment: /tmp/outfile will work fine on Windows, assuming you have C:\tmp (or whatever drive letter your CGI is running on).

Comment: Actually, changing `/tmp/outfile` to `C:\UniServer\tmp\outfile` crashed the script entirely.

Comment: @Chiffa When Apache gives 500, always look into server error log. It should tell you where the problem is.

Comment: @Palec, sorry, I am new to Perl, didn't know about the `\\` issue. I think your advice would work eventually.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46539/discussion-between-chiffa-and-palec)