# A Perl /CGI script to accept different upload files

Tags: perl, file-upload, cgi

Related to this -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487257/a-perl-cgi-script-for-uploading-files -- question, I have another one: can this:
 http://www.seaglass.com/file-upload-pl.html
script be modified so that it would accept different input files and save them as different output files, and not just overwrite the single `output` file?
I'm new to Perl/CGI, so I wouldn't see an obvious answer.

Comment: Not sure why this is ON HOLD.  This is related to another thread by the op, but different enough to warrant a separate question.  I guess if you don't read the first thread, perhaps there isn't enough info here as a stand-alone question.  But still, the op is looking for some simple help learning Perl/CGI and I would have hoped we could have helped.

Comment: @jimtut I get it completely. I was just guessing what OP wants to do, while mentioning the limitations of my solution. Also it is “do my job for me” type of question, showing no effort to solve the problem. Benefit for future visitors is terribly low, too. Two reasons for closing, one for downvoting. Not a good score. I think we helped, but this question needs to be fixed before it deserves to be reopened.

Comment: I wanted to know of a simple way. I should do my research and learn more Perl, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

In `$basename` you already have name of the file. You do not have to write the uploaded file into `/tmp/outfile`; you can construct the path dynamically, depending on `$basename`.

Create a directory where you want to place the files. I assume it will still be `C:\tmp`. Instead of

```
open(OUTFILE, ">/tmp/outfile")
```

write

```
open(OUTFILE, ">/tmp/$basename")
```

and it should work. Taint is removed from `$upfile` inside `GetBasename()`, even before `$basename` is created. But this is not safe, still. Before giving it to `open()`, you should remove all unwanted characters from the file name, e.g.

```
$basename =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9_.-]//g;
$basename =~ s/^[^A-Za-z0-9]*//;
```

If `$basename` is empty now, you have to chose a name other way. Also if file of the same name already exists, you have to choose whether you want to overwrite it or make up a unique name. My current solution just overwrites.

If you want to know more about regular expressions, look at [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) manual page.